# want to handle change in checkbox in my reactjs

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-hooks

i am trying to handle checkbox in my react app but i am not able to it.
here is my usestate of communication

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  phone: "",
  notice: { paper: true, court: false, labour: false }
});
```

below is my change handler for that

```
const handleDataChange = (event) => {
  setData({ ...data, ...notice, [e.target.id]: ![e.target.value] });
};
```

will any one look into this and help me out

Comment: Where do you want to store the `ids` of checkboxes?. Also you are spreading `notice` without having access to it since it is a property of  `data` object.

Comment: Are you checkbox ids `paper`, `court`, and `labour`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const handleDataChange = (event) => {
    setData({
        ...data,
        notice: {
            ...data.notice,
            [event.target.id]: !event.target.checked
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: please omit the not operator i forgot

Comment: Does he not want it to be there? I mean, the operator makes no sense here, but I don't know what his idea is.

Comment: oops sorry its fine i over analyze the situation hes. just leave it